# Hierarchical vertical and horizontal division of HTML elements

Tags: html, layout

I apologize if this question is already answered, this seems like a basic problem, but I have not been able to find a solution.

**Problem:**

I would like to arrange elements in HTML in this layout (where `a` and `b` are arbitrary elements):

```
aa
 a
bb
 b
```

**Example:**

I tried this, using buttons as arbitrary elements ([JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qd0vr3/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <style>
            .left {
                float: left;
                /*display: inline-block;*/
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <button type="button">a</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <button type="button">a</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button">a</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <button type="button">b</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <button type="button">b</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button">b</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

But I got this:

```
aabb
 a b
```

When I use `inline-block` instead I get this (still wrong):

```
 a
aa
 b
bb
```

Any solution? Is there a different approach I should use?

Answer (score 1):

Put a wrapper-class to your surrounding divs:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="left">
            <div>
                <button type="button">a</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <div>
                <button type="button">a</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button">a</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And use this css:

```
 .left {
     float: left;
 }

.wrapper {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/L7qd0vr3/3/

Answer (score 0):

Your html is wrong. Use clear:both and fix html.

```
    <div>
        <div class="left">
            <div>
                <button type="button">a</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <div>
                <button type="button">a</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button">a</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Should be

```
<div>
        <div class="left">
            <div>
                <button type="button">a</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="button">a</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <div>
                <button type="button">a</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/L7qd0vr3/1/
Still, not looking like in my example.